Powering two 12VDC servos with a 24VDC supply
If I have two servos rated as 12VDC with a maximum draw of 2A. Can these be reliably powered in series using a 24VDC supply?
My question is how stable would the voltage be expected to be given the current draw will vary with use of either servo.
Doing so would remove the need to step-down to 12VDC and reduce heat output from such conversion if it were to scale to many servo pairs.

Do you mean putting the two servos in series?

@JohnD aye I do, sorry

I doubt it would work- The voltage across each servo could change and exceed 12 V by a lot if the current draw differed enough, not to mention that any interface signals in the "top" servo (if any) would not be referenced to ground.

@JohnD thanks for the answer!

Your talking about "heat output" makes me think you plan to use an LDO for voltage regulation, like a LM7812 or LM1117. Do not use an LDO. They have unacceptable power consumption. Use a modern switching regulator.

No, and you'll likely damage one or more of the servos if you try.
They will not 'share' the voltage evenly and the one that gets more volts will quite likely die in a shorted condition, subjecting the other to overvoltage.
Another problem is that the control input is referenced to servo ground, so it might well damage whatever you've got it connected to.
Use a buck converter.

No.  The classic voltage divider that you're probably thinking of, relies on constant resistance/impedance (depending on whether we're talking about DC/AC analysis).  If they're not constant, then the ratio will change accordingly.
You might think of it kinda like 2 springs that are tied together and stretched between two endpoints.  If they're equal strength, then the midpoint will be halfway in between.  If they're different, the midpoint will be towards the stronger one.  If they somehow change strength (or if something else is added to pull on it too), then the midpoint moves.
A servo - or any motor that changes its speed, load, or anything else - necessarily changes its impedance, often wildly.  When first starting, or under a heavy load (physically the same thing: the speed it "wants" to run vs the speed it's actually running), it will be much closer to a short-circuit (really strong spring), and so it will get close to zero voltage across it in that moment, which causes the other one to see the entire supply.
Semiconductors often fail short-circuit, so if the controller in the non-loaded servo does that, it may reverse the situation and cause the original one to fail the same way.  Now you've shorted the entire supply, which may itself then fail.
It's more likely though, that the original fail-short burns itself into an open (becomes a fuse), which stops the chain of events there, but you still have a dead servo and a possibly damaged one.
